# one-time payment with Laravel Cashier without subscription

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm Planning to use Laravel Cashier for one-time payments with Stripe. It  says in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/billing#introduction):

> If you're only performing "one-off" charges and do not offer subscriptions, you should not use Cashier.

However, I was able to charge the user without subscription using the following code:

```
$amount = $request['amount];
Stripe::setApiKey(Config::get('stripe.secret_key'));
$token = $input['stripeToken'];
$user = Auth::user();
return $user->charge($amount * 100, ['source' => $token]);
```

And it worked! I'm wondering is there a problem with this approach? Why they suggested to not use Cashier? Is it gonna cause problems along the way? Please let me know what do you think?

Comment: This is probably better asked either on [GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/issues) or a forum like [Laravel.io](https://laravel.io/forum). I can't answer definitively, but my guess is Cashier is meant for subscriptions, so if you _only need single charges_, don't use it. If you're using subscriptions and occasionally need single charges as well, you should be okay.

Comment: That warning is no longer present in Laravel 6.x documentation.

Comment: from where it comes "$input['stripeToken']"? from the previous form?

Answer (score 3):

As currently implemented, it's safe to do this. You can see the code for the `charge` method here: https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/822b6535e755fd36dec8ecceb52cc8909c8a953e/src/Billable.php#L37

That said, given the explicit warning that Cashier isn't *intended* for this sort of use, it's your own fault if the `charge` function gets modified in a way that breaks your app somewhere down the line.

There's not much reason to use Cashier in this situation, either. Using the SDK's `Stripe\Charge` class directly will be cleaner code, and you don't take on the risk of misusing a different library.

Comment: You're right. I actually made it work using SDK too. But i was wondering if using cashier is an option too. thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

</head>
<body>

        <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
        <br><br>
        <h1 align="center">One Time Charge</h1>
        <form method = "post" action = "{{route('charge')}}" id="form">
        @csrf

        <div class="form form-cb" align="center"> 

                        Name on Card:    <input type="text" id="card-holder-name" required>  
                        <br>                <br> 
                        <div id="card-element" style="width: 300px;">
                        <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->           
                        </div>

                        <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
                        <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div><br>
                        <button disabled style="background-color:skyblue;color:black">$1.00 USD</button><br><br>  
                        <button id="card-button" style="background-color: green;color:white;font-size:20px;" />Pay
                        </button>   
        </div>

        </form>
<script>

    var stripe = Stripe('Your Stripe-key');
    var elements = stripe.elements();
    var cardElement = elements.create('card');

    cardElement.mount('#card-element');

    // Add an instance of the card UI component into the `card-element` <div>
    var cardHolderName = document.getElementById('card-holder-name');
    var cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');

    cardButton.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
    var { paymentMethod, error } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod(
        'card', cardElement, {
            billing_details: { name: cardHolderName.value }
        }
    );
    if (error) {
        console.log('error');
        } else {
                var payment_id = paymentMethod.id;
                createPayment(payment_id);
        }   
    });

    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    // Submit the form with the token ID.
    function createPayment(payment_id) {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'payment_id');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value',payment_id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
    // Submit the form

    form.submit();

    }

</script>


</body>
</html>
```